# Authorization failed: The resource could not be found. (HTTP 404)

Tags: authentication, monitoring, openstack, keystone

I'm trying to run the monitoring service in openstack, but I'm receiving this error:

```
~$ monasca metric-list
Authorization failed: The resource could not be found. (HTTP 404)
```

When I check the log file this is why I found:

```
2016-09-20 10:27:36.357 27771 WARNING keystonemiddleware.auth_token [-] Fetch revocation list failed, fallback to online validation.
2016-09-20 10:27:36.376 27771 ERROR keystonemiddleware.auth_token [-] Bad response code while validating token: 403
2016-09-20 10:27:36.377 27771 WARNING keystonemiddleware.auth_token [-] Identity response: {"error": {"message": "You are not authorized to perform the requested action, identity:validate_token.", "code": 403, "title": "Forbidden"}}
2016-09-20 10:27:36.377 27771 CRITICAL keystonemiddleware.auth_token [-] Unable to validate token: Failed to fetch token data from identity server
```

This is the services, projects, users , role and endpoints in keystone

```
+----------------------------------+----------+------------+
| ID                               | Name     | Type       |
+----------------------------------+----------+------------+
| 1c38cf31124d404783561793fc1fb7f0 | monasca  | monitoring |
| 1eb72109ea604b6e8f2bd264787ca370 | keystone | identity   |
+----------------------------------+----------+------------+
+----------------------------------+---------+
| ID                               | Name    |
+----------------------------------+---------+
| 733a0a1369f94f6ab31b8875ef19e0ee | service |
| 9e732f1a2aca48e098daf62bb230f85e | monasca |
| f2df2111f893434f83fda7d5bd6cac4a | admin   |
+----------------------------------+---------+ 
+----------------------------------+---------------+
| ID                               | Name          |
+----------------------------------+---------------+
| 3a1b8582a11f4e07b3a21e84e9fb7c23 | monasca-user  |
| 559752237e824d81a6133494b63c5789 | monasca-agent |
| 5bcf19af4e8e4067a5679e6a0f2f88f1 | admin         |
+----------------------------------+---------------+
+----------------------------------+---------------+
| ID                               | Name          |
+----------------------------------+---------------+
| 1679c1c099b543db96ac4412be21b15a | admin         |
| 6ca31578625c49568085284dee72e4b8 | monasca-agent |
| 9fe2ff9ee4384b1894a90878d3e92bab | _member_      |
| a3267f589e7342ceaedef57ea9e4aac2 | monasca-user  |
+----------------------------------+---------------+
+----------------------------------+-----------+--------------+--------------+---------+-----------+------------------------------+
| ID                               | Region    | Service Name | Service     Type | Enabled | Interface | URL                          |
+----------------------------------+-----------+--------------+--------------+---------+-----------+------------------------------+
| 3fbfc68e9f894e47846b896c6c8d3f3e | RegionOne | keystone     | identity     | True    | internal  | http://controller:5000/v2.0  |
| 470043a7f6364add902548df6fb7b60e | RegionOne | monasca      | monitoring   | True    | public    | http://localhost:8082/v2.0   |
| 9e68606b37084cbeb95106ff1bede0cb | RegionOne | monasca      | monitoring   | True    | internal  | http://localhost:8082/v2.0   |
| b4273c72671e4fac99e7d2bc6334156c | RegionOne | monasca      | monitoring   | True    | admin     | http://localhost:8082/v2.0   |
| d27bb34d619443658ca745b9fee1c967 | RegionOne | keystone     | identity     | True    | admin     | http://controller:35357/v2.0 |
| f736ebca8ac24b78bdf1dff60ac86ab1 | RegionOne | keystone     | identity     | True    | public    | http://controller:5000/v2.0  |
+----------------------------------+-----------+--------------+--------------+---------+-----------+------------------------------+
```

this is the keystone section in my api.conf file:

```
[keystone_authtoken]
identity_uri = http://controller:35357
auth_uri = http://controller:5000/v3
admin_password = PASSWORD
admin_user = monasca-user
admin_tenant_name = monasca
cafile =
certfile =
keyfile =
insecure = false
```

file to get the token for the identity service

```
export OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_ID=default
export OS_USER_DOMAIN_ID=default
export OS_PROJECT_NAME=admin
export OS_TENANT_NAME=admin
export OS_USERNAME=admin
export OS_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://controller:35357/v3
export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
```

and for the monitoring service

```
export OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_ID=default
export OS_USER_DOMAIN_ID=default
export OS_PROJECT_NAME=monasca
export OS_TENANT_NAME=monasca
export OS_USERNAME=monasca-user
export OS_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://controller:35357/
export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
```

I can find what is wrong with the configuration

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to run the following command?

```
openstack token issue
```

Why do you have localhost in endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

you can use --debug option for monasca commands to get more details

I think the problem is that you register keystone endpoint with version specified while in env var the version is another one. it is recommended that not include version number in endpoint, especially the keystone one. Please check install manuals and follow its instructions